# 50% chance randomizer capping out at 15 numbers in a row, why?

Tags: c++

I'm playing around with rand() and srand() functions and I was trying to make a counter for how many 1's I could get in a row with a 50/50 generator, yet it seems that it caps out at 15 numbers in a row.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int MostInARow = 0, CurrentInARow;
    bool randomised;
    srand((int)time(NULL));
    for (long int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
        CurrentInARow = 0;
        randomised = rand() % 2;
        while (randomised) {
            randomised = rand() % 2;
            CurrentInARow++;
        }

        if (CurrentInARow > MostInARow) {
            system("CLS");
            MostInARow = CurrentInARow;
            cout << MostInARow;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'd love to learn why this happens.

Comment: Dunno what you mean. I get different results on every run. Most I got were 26 in a row... But keep in mind that you are dealing with a Pseudo-RNG. If you want a better RNG you need something that takes entropy into account, eg. OpenSSL

Comment: Side note: You (usually) don't get good random distributions by modulo calculations. Better: `value = rand() > RAND_MAX/2`.

Comment: Because the probability of 15 ones in a row is 0.5^15 = 0.00003052, that is pretty rare

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov there's 100,000,000 attempts, you'd expect something like a 24 streak

Comment: I tried what @Aconcagua said. It makes it only a little better for me. I guess its the best a Pseudo-RNG can do... its not really random

Comment: Side note: [`std::bernoulli_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/bernoulli_distribution) generates bools directly

Comment: @Caleth I bet he didn't wait even a million attempts out of these (because he runs randomization until first 0 appears)

Comment: The quality of `rand` varies with implementations, what compiler are you using? The MSVC one has [RAND_MAX of 32767](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/398ax69y(v=vs.140)), it might not support 1 in 32768 events too well.

Comment: Off-topic: There's absolutely no need to cast the result of `time` – it is converted to appropriate type automatically. Apart from you chose the bad type anyway, `srand` accepts **`unsigned`** `int`...

Comment: If your generator has 32 bit periodicity (it probably does), start it at 1 and generate the analysis on the entire sequence. It won't take that long. A linear congruential generator will not get the uniform distribution higher moments anywhere near correct. That's life I'm afraid. Mersenne Twister does slightly better, and is in the C++ standard library from C++11.

Comment: `rand()` can be considered deprecated. It is fine for toy random numbers when you do not need quality randomness. If you do expect high quality randomness you are using the wrong tool. Use `<random>`

Comment: About [`using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)...

Comment: Turns out it was just the compiler so @Nidhoegger 's solution was right, I compiler this program in Visual Studio and it only gave me a max of 15, but in a different online compiler I managed to get up to 29

Comment: [rand() Considered Harmful - Stephan T. Lavavej](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)

Comment: You can check twice as many sequences if you check for the zeros as well: `srand(time(nullptr)); auto current = rand() > RAND_MAX/2; for(...) { while(rand() > ... == current) {...} current = !current; /* print new maximum */ }`.

Comment: Afaik nothing but common sense forbids `rand()` to be `int rand() { return 42; }`, hence there isnt much more to the answer than: You expected `rand` to do something which it is not guaranteed to do.

Comment: @RichardCritten: That presentation is a pretty childish one in my opinion. Donald Knuth (worked on LCGs) is probably one of the finest scientific programmers ever to live, and he was well aware of the deficiencies of a LCG. Off point, but `NULL` is not an abomination. In other words, there's nothing at all wrong with `rand()` so long as you know what you're doing.

Comment: @Bathsheba things change and sometimes humor helps the message.  I also think STL is also owed some respect.

Comment: @Bathsheba `NULL` has an *implementation-defined* type. It might be `int`, it might be `std::nullptr_t`. You might have code that (wrongly) assumes that it's `void *`. Abominable.

Comment: The well known limitation of LCGs demonstrate themselves most clearly in the behaviour of the low order bits of the output.  Hence the advice from @Aconcagua to extract high order bit(s) and not % to get the randomness you need.